# Finding common rows (intersection) in two Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersect

Assume I have two dataframes of this format (call them `df1` and `df2`):

```
+------------------------+------------------------+--------+
|        user_id         |      business_id       | rating |
+------------------------+------------------------+--------+
| rLtl8ZkDX5vH5nAx9C3q5Q | eIxSLxzIlfExI6vgAbn2JA |      4 |
| C6IOtaaYdLIT5fWd7ZYIuA | eIxSLxzIlfExI6vgAbn2JA |      5 |
| mlBC3pN9GXlUUfQi1qBBZA | KoIRdcIfh3XWxiCeV1BDmA |      3 |
+------------------------+------------------------+--------+
```

I'm looking to get a dataframe of all the rows that have a common `user_id` in `df1` and `df2`. (ie. if a `user_id` is in both `df1` and `df2`, include the two rows in the output dataframe)

I can think of many ways to approach this, but they all strike me as clunky. For example, we could find all the unique `user_id`s in each dataframe, create a set of each, find their intersection, filter the two dataframes with the resulting set and concatenate the two filtered dataframes.

Maybe that's the best approach, but I know Pandas is clever. Is there a simpler way to do this? I've looked at `merge` but I don't think that's what I need.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

My understanding is that this question is better answered over in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921943/pandas-intersection-of-two-data-frames-based-on-column-entries).

But briefly, the answer to the OP with this method is simply:

```
s1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['user_id'])
```

Which gives `s1` with 5 columns: `user_id` and the other two columns from each of `df1` and `df2`.

Answer (score 19):

If I understand you correctly, you can use a combination of `Series.isin()` and `DataFrame.append()`:

```
In [80]: df1
Out[80]:
   rating  user_id
0       2  0x21abL
1       1  0x21abL
2       1   0xdafL
3       0  0x21abL
4       4  0x1d14L
5       2  0x21abL
6       1  0x21abL
7       0   0xdafL
8       4  0x1d14L
9       1  0x21abL

In [81]: df2
Out[81]:
   rating      user_id
0       2      0x1d14L
1       1    0xdbdcad7
2       1      0x21abL
3       3      0x21abL
4       3      0x21abL
5       1  0x5734a81e2
6       2      0x1d14L
7       0       0xdafL
8       0      0x1d14L
9       4  0x5734a81e2

In [82]: ind = df2.user_id.isin(df1.user_id) & df1.user_id.isin(df2.user_id)

In [83]: ind
Out[83]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
7     True
8     True
9    False
Name: user_id, dtype: bool

In [84]: df1[ind].append(df2[ind])
Out[84]:
   rating  user_id
0       2  0x21abL
2       1   0xdafL
3       0  0x21abL
4       4  0x1d14L
6       1  0x21abL
7       0   0xdafL
8       4  0x1d14L
0       2  0x1d14L
2       1  0x21abL
3       3  0x21abL
4       3  0x21abL
6       2  0x1d14L
7       0   0xdafL
8       0  0x1d14L
```

This is essentially the algorithm you described as "clunky", using idiomatic `pandas` methods. Note the duplicate row indices. Also, note that this won't give you the expected output if `df1` and `df2` have no overlapping row indices, i.e., if

```
In [93]: df1.index & df2.index
Out[93]: Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
```

In fact, it won't give the expected output if their row indices are not equal.

Comment: Ah. I had thought about that, but it doesn't give me what I want. I'm looking to have the two rows as two separate rows in the output dataframe. This solution instead doubles the number of columns and uses prefixes. I don't think there's a way to use `merge` to have create the two separate rows.

Comment: +1 for merge, but looks like OP wants a bit different output. I've created what looks like he need but I'm not sure it most elegant pandas solution

Comment: This will only work if `df1` and `df2` are of the same length. Otherwise, this `df2.user_id.isin(df1.user_id) & df1.user_id.isin(df2.user_id)` won't be able to broadcast together.

Comment: I think it's solvable using `df1 = df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]; df2 = df2[df2.index.isin(df1.index)]`

Comment: Why do you need the & here? `df2.user_id.isin(df1.user_id) & df1.user_id.isin(df2.user_id)`

Answer (score 5):

In SQL, this problem could be solved by several methods:

```
select * from df1 where exists (select * from df2 where df2.user_id = df1.user_id)
union all
select * from df2 where exists (select * from df1 where df1.user_id = df2.user_id)
```

or join and then unpivot (possible in SQL server)

```
select
    df1.user_id,
    c.rating
from df1
    inner join df2 on df2.user_i = df1.user_id
    outer apply (
        select df1.rating union all
        select df2.rating
    ) as c
```

Second one could be written in pandas with something like:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"user_id":[1,2,3], "rating":[10, 15, 20]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"user_id":[3,4,5], "rating":[30, 35, 40]})
>>>
>>> df4 = df[['user_id', 'rating_1']].rename(columns={'rating_1':'rating'})
>>> df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='user_id', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
>>> df3 = df[['user_id', 'rating_1']].rename(columns={'rating_1':'rating'})
>>> df4 = df[['user_id', 'rating_2']].rename(columns={'rating_2':'rating'})
>>> pd.concat([df3, df4], axis=0)
   user_id  rating
0        3      20
0        3      30
```

Comment: can the second method be optimised /shortened ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for `n` DataFrames and `k` colums by using `pd.Index.intersection`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
from typing import Union

def dataframe_intersection(
    dataframes: list[pd.DataFrame], by: Union[list, str]
) -> list[pd.DataFrame]:
    set_index = [d.set_index(by) for d in dataframes]
    index_intersection = reduce(pd.Index.intersection, [d.index for d in set_index])
    intersected = [df.loc[index_intersection].reset_index() for df in set_index]

    return intersected

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"user_id":[1,2,3], "business_id": ['a', 'b', 'c'], "rating":[10, 15, 20]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"user_id":[3,4,5], "business_id": ['c', 'd', 'e'], "rating":[30, 35, 40]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"user_id":[3,3,3], "business_id": ['f', 'c', 'f'], "rating":[50, 70, 80]})

df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
```

This gives

```py
>>> pd.concat(dataframe_intersection(df_list, by='user_id'))
   user_id business_id  rating
0        3           c      20
0        3           c      30
0        3           f      50
1        3           c      70
2        3           f      80
```

And

```py
>>> pd.concat(dataframe_intersection(df_list, by=['user_id', 'business_id']))
   user_id business_id  rating
0        3           c      20
0        3           c      30
0        3           c      70
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple solution:

df1[df1 == df2].dropna()