# Intersection of two pandas dataframes based on column entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersection

Suppose I have two DataFrames like so:

```
>>dfA
        S        T            prob
0   ! ! !    ! ! !   8.1623999e-05
1   ! ! !  ! ! ! "   0.00354090007
2   ! ! !  ! ! ! .   0.00210241997
3   ! ! !  ! ! ! ?  6.55684998e-05
4   ! ! !  ! ! !       0.203119993
5   ! ! !  ! ! ! ”  6.62070015e-05
6   ! ! !      ! !   0.00481862016
7   ! ! !        !    0.0274260994
8   ! ! !  " ! ! !  7.99940026e-05
9   ! ! !      " !  1.51188997e-05
10  ! ! !        "  8.50678989e-05

>>dfB
        S        T                              knstats
0   ! ! !  ! ! ! !              knstats=2,391,104,64,25
1   ! ! !  ! ! ! "                 knstats=4,391,6,64,2
2   ! ! !  ! ! ! .                 knstats=4,391,5,64,2
3   ! ! !  ! ! ! ?                 knstats=1,391,4,64,4
4   ! ! !    ! ! !            knstats=220,391,303,64,55
5   ! ! !      ! !            knstats=16,391,957,64,115
6   ! ! !        !           knstats=28,391,5659,64,932
7   ! ! !  " ! ! !                 knstats=2,391,2,64,1
8   ! ! !      " !               knstats=1,391,37,64,13
9   ! ! !        "  knstats=2,391,1.11721e+06,64,180642
10  ! !        . "        knstats=2,391,120527,64,20368
```

I want to create a new DataFrame which is composed of the rows which have matching "S" and "T" entries in both matrices, along with the `prob` column from `dfA` and the `knstats` column from `dfB`. The result should look something like the following, and it is important that the order is the same:

```
       S        T            prob                              knstats
0  ! ! !  ! ! ! !   8.1623999e-05              knstats=2,391,104,64,25
1  ! ! !  ! ! ! "   0.00354090007                 knstats=4,391,6,64,2
2  ! ! !  ! ! ! .   0.00210241997                 knstats=4,391,5,64,2
3  ! ! !  ! ! ! ?  6.55684998e-05                 knstats=1,391,4,64,4
4  ! ! !    ! ! !     0.203119993            knstats=220,391,303,64,55
5  ! ! !      ! !   0.00481862016            knstats=16,391,957,64,115
6  ! ! !        !    0.0274260994           knstats=28,391,5659,64,932
7  ! ! !  " ! ! !  7.99940026e-05                 knstats=2,391,2,64,1
8  ! ! !      " !  1.51188997e-05               knstats=1,391,37,64,13
9  ! ! !        "  8.50678989e-05  knstats=2,391,1.11721e+06,64,180642
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can merge them so:

```
s1 = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, how='inner', on=['S', 'T'])
```

To drop NA rows:

```
s1.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: I am not interested in simply merging them, but taking the intersection. That is, if there is a row where 'S' and 'T' do not have both prob and knstats, I want to get rid of that row. You'll notice that dfA and dfB do not match up exactly. However, this seems like a good first step. How can I prune the rows with NaN values in either prob or knstats in the output matrix?

Comment: Changed to how='inner', that will compute the intersection based on 'S' an 'T'

Comment: Also, you can use dropna to drop rows with any NaN's. Edited my answer

Comment: This is a join, not an intersection

Comment: by definition: an intersection == an equality join on all columns

Answer (score 1):

To select the rows from the two dataframes where S and T values intersect, one could use `Index.intersection()`. The idea is to find the common rows (i.e. intersection) in S and T columns in the two dataframes and select only those rows.

```py
# convert S and T columns into MultiIndex
dfA_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(dfA[['S', 'T']])
dfB_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(dfB[['S', 'T']])
# get intersecting rows in S and T
common_idx = dfA_idx.intersection(dfB_idx)
# filter rows where S and T intersect
dfA_common = dfA.set_index(['S', 'T']).reindex(common_idx).reset_index()
dfB_common = dfB.set_index(['S', 'T']).reindex(common_idx).reset_index()
```

The concatenation of these frames will produce the same result as `merge()`, i.e.

```py
x = dfA_common.join(dfB_common[['knstats']])
y = dfA.merge(dfB, on=['S', 'T'])
x.equals(y)                                    # True
```

[image: result]