# Python Pandas - drop rows based on columns of 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set-intersection

I have 2 dataframes with a column called `frames`. The dataframes are about data extracted from 2 videos recorded at the same time of two participants. The data lacks some frames (different per video) due to failed tracking. I want to take an intersection based on the frame integer value `df['frame']`.

A similar question is posted here: [Pandas - intersection of two data frames based on column entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921943/pandas-intersection-of-two-data-frames-based-on-column-entries)
, but the accepted answer is a join, not an intersection.

## Example data

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'frame': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'frame': [2, 3, 4]})
```

## Desired output

Removed rows not in union of `df1['frame']` and `df2['frame']`

```
>>> print(df1)
   frame
1      2
2      3

>>> print(df2)
   frame
0      2
1      3
```

(I can reset the index after I'm done processing with `df1.reset_index(drop=True)`)

## Tried

I thought of first getting the intersection of the frames column of both dataframes with:

```
df1_idx = df1['frame']
df2_idx = df2['frame']
intersection_idx = df1_idx.intersection(df2_idx)
```

Error:

```
File "/*python_path*/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3081, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'intersection'
```

After getting the frame indexes that are in both dataframes, I was thinking of doing something like (mentioned in: [dropping rows from dataframe based on a "not in" condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965295/dropping-rows-from-dataframe-based-on-a-not-in-condition)):

```
df1 = df1.drop(df[~df['frame'].isin(intersection_idx)])
```

## System

Python 3.6.5 with pandas 0.22.0 installed with Anaconda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about

```
df1[df1.frame.isin(df2.frame)]
Out: 
   frame
1      2
2      3

df2[df2.frame.isin(df1.frame)]
Out: 
   frame
0      2
1      3
```