# How to compare columns of two different data frames and keep the common values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames with same column but different values, out of which some are same and some are different. I want to compare both columns and keep the common values.

`df1` :

```
  A B C
  1 1 1
  2 4 6
  3 7 9
  4 9 0
  6 0 1
```

`df2` :

```
  A D E
  1 5 7
  5 6 9
  2 3 5
  7 6 8
  3 7 0
```

This is what I am expecting after comparison

`df2` :

```
  A D E
  1 5 7
  2 3 5
  3 7 0
```

Comment: Perhaps this can be useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921943/pandas-intersection-of-two-data-frames-based-on-column-entries

Comment: I guess you want to use something like merging `df1` and `df2` based on the column `A`

Comment: I don't want to merge them, I want to save the common points only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Index.intersection()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) to find the matching columns and do a inner merge finally [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to keep `df2.columns`:

```
match=df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns).tolist() #finds matching cols in both df
df2.merge(df1,on=match).reindex(df2.columns,axis=1) #merge and reindex to df2.columns
```

---

```
   A  D  E
0  1  5  7
1  2  3  5
2  3  7  0
```

Comment: Using this, I am getting the merged values and not the common ones.

Comment: @Bhavishya what is the difference? can you elaborate, this gets exactly what you posted as desired answer

Comment: I have around 250k entries in df1 and around 1.1m entries in df2, so after keeping just the common values I should get less than or equal to 250k entries in df2 but I'm getting around 1m entries instead.