# How to merge two python tables into one table which only shows common table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

So I have table 1 which is the properties I own

and I have table 2 the tables of government database

table 1: 1 john street, 2 john street, 3 john street, 4 john street

table 2: 1 Clive Street, 2 john street, 2 fred street, 4 john street

I WANT A TABLE WHICH PROVIDES THE COMMON PROPERTIES:

Desired output table:  2 John street, 4 John Street

How can I achieve this with a merge on Pandas?

Comment: Python doesn't have "tables" or "dataframes". Please remember to use the [tag:pandas] tag when asking about Pandas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - intersection of two data frames based on column entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921943/pandas-intersection-of-two-data-frames-based-on-column-entries)

Answer (score 0):

```
s=pd.merge(table1,table2,on='john street', how='left')
```

if you want just these two columns, you can do that:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(s, columns = ['john street', 'john street'])
```