# How can I find intersect dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, intersection, numpy-ndarray

I have two dataframes like this.But, column zero is a ndarray. I want to find intersect dataframes.

a1 =

```
 0                   |  1
 [39]                |  6000000
 [49] [50] [51] [52] |  84100 
 [49]                |  95400
 [20]                |  65089
```

a2 =

```
 0                   |  1
 [49] [50] [51] [52] |  84100 
 [38] [50]           |  530400
 [52]                |  60611
 [20]                |  65089
```

expected output:

a3 =

```
 0                   |  1
 [49] [50] [51] [52] |  84100 
 [20]                |  65089
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `a1.merge(a2)` ??

Comment: Colunm zero is a ndarray. Not working.

Comment: have a look to: [\[1\]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618912/finding-common-rows-intersection-in-two-pandas-dataframes][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just make a boolean mask by comparison using the [numpy.array.all method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
a1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[0], [0,1,2], [3], [4]], 
                    'b':[0, 1000, 2000, 3000]})
a2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[0], [0,1,2], [4], [6]], 
                    'b':[0, 1000, 88000, 6000]})

a3 = a1[(a1==a2).values.all(axis=1)]
```

which returns:

```
     a            b
0      [0]        0
1   [0, 1, 2]   1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution... But, i got the error " Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects ".. i am trying to figure out why?

Comment: I'm guessing your example doesn't reflect the true nature of your data. The error is probably being thrown because your two dataframes have different column names.

Comment: I am sure that two dataframes have the same colunm name.

Comment: This may help: [Pandas can only compare identically labeled dataframe objects error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548370/pandas-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-dataframe-objects-error). I still suspect there is a labelling issue.

Comment: I found that my dataframes have different shapes.. i applied to your code.. i got the same error..