# python two csv files pandas compare

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to compare two csv file. I want to compare similarity user_name if the user_name have same name as table1 and table2 create table3 print

for example

```
table1.csv
id_Acco,     user_name,       post_time
1543603,     SameDavie ,      "2020/09/06"
1543595,     Johntim,         "2020/09/11"
1558245,     ACAtesdfgsf ,    "2020/09/19"

table2.csv
id_Acco,     user_name,     post_time
1543603,    SameDavie,      "2020/09/06"
1543595,    Johntim ,       "2020/09/11"
1558245,    Davidwillian,   "2020/09/19"
```

OutPut

```
table3.csv

id_Acco,     user_name,     post_time
1543603,     SameDavie ,    "2020/09/06"
1543595,     Johntim ,      "2020/09/11"
```

code

```
`A = pd.read_csv(r'table1.csv')
 B= pd.read_csv(r'table2.csv')
 print(A-B) 
 print(B-A)
```

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618912/finding-common-rows-intersection-in-two-pandas-dataframes

Comment: Do the rows matter or do you just want a list of the user names that appear in both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `concat` A and B and check for `duplicated` records:

```
z = pd.concat([A, B])[['user_name']]
z.loc[z.duplicated()].to_csv('table3.csv')
```

Output (in `table3.csv`):

```
   user_name
0  SameDavie
1    Johntim
```

P.S. And if you have those trailing spaces sometimes in your files like you have in the example, you may want to strip them after concatenation:

```
z = pd.concat([A, B])['user_name'].str.strip()
z.loc[z.duplicated()].to_frame().to_csv('table3.csv')
```

Comment: thank you and another question how can I pass id_Acco and post_time after it check for duplicated

Comment: If you don't specify the column for `z` then it will use all of them, so `z = pd.concat([A, B])` as the first line, and then the same `z.loc[z.duplicated()]` (I'm assuming you stripped those spaces already -- if not, you can do it after concatenation)